# Spark retrying stage even though UI shows all tasks completed successfully

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm running a spark filesource streaming job in EMR cluster of AWS. It is not rare in EMR to lose executors due to nodes going offline which can cause some tasks to fail.
Although in my case, how I understand it is tasks are being re-tried and successfully completed but still in spark UI , I can see the stage being retried. Where am I going wrong in my understanding?
Please refer to the image below where number of tasks are marked as blue and stage retries marked in red.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In EMR, you lose executors if they are running on spot instances (if you use spot for TASK nodes), the probability of spot instance interruption increases with time, so you can reduce the probability of retry by increasing the executors number (and the resources) in order to finish the job faster.

There are another reasons for task failure:

- A problem with an external API or I/O (reading from disk with low throughput, API limit or quota, ...)
- the executor memory is not enough to process the data
- skewed data in your partitions (after a group by or repartition, you can have unbalanced partition sizes)

I suggest that you try to increase executor memory, and to double the number of executors. And for the cost, spark retried the stage for 20 hours, when by doubling the number of executors, it may finish it in the half of the first retry (~ 4 hours).

Comment: In the spark UI, for example for the first try it shows 14463 tasks succeeded out of 14463 total marked in blue box. Yet, why does the spark retry the stage?

Comment: Not convinced u andwered the question.

Comment: For the spark UI, I faced the same problem before with spark 2.4, I observed that the number of succeeded tasks is actually the number of finished tasks, and when spark retry the tasks in the same stage, we will have something like `130/100 (30 failed)`. You can click on the blue line (start at ...) to see the tasks details (how many tasks have been created and how many have succeeded and failed)